# Passing variable from one js to another js file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm just getting started with Nodejs, so please bear with me

I store my DB setting on the first JS, `connect.js` :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = function(connectDB) {
  var connectDB = {};

  connectDB.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //db params
  });

  connectDB.connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });

return connectDB;
};
```

Then I stored my query in another JS file, lets call it `dbManager.js` :

```
var db = require('./connect')(connectDB);

var test_connection = connectDB.connection.query('SELECT * FROM `test`', function (error, results, fields) {
  console.log(results);
});

exports.test = test_connection;
```

My goal is to pass the `connection` variable from `connect.js` to `dbManager.js`, so I could use it for running some queries.

The above code return an error, which said the variable is not passed successfully to `dbManager.js` :

```
ReferenceError: connectDB is not defined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like you need a common config file that is shared between the 2 and you can update and share things there.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell I did some googling and found out i could do something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380561/how-to-pass-variables-into-nodejs-modules

The above code is my implementation, which is not working yet

Comment: Yes exactly. Basically the same concept. Good find!

Comment: you are getting syntax error, because in an object, to define property you have to use `:` and not `=`, according to your code `connection` is a property of `connectDB`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is because you cant define variables within an object literal using `var`.

e.g., you can't do the following,

```
var t = {
    "r": 4,
    var g = 5;
};
```

You can do this,

```
var t = {
    "r": 4,
    "g" : 5
};
```

And to access the properties of the object you can do,

```
console.log(t["r"]);
console.log(t.g);
```

In your code the problem is declaring a variable inside an object literal. Yo could do,

```
var connectDB = {};
connectDB.connection = mysql.createConnection({
  //DB params
});
connectDB.connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connectDB.connection.threadId);
});

return connectDB;
```

**Edit1** As per OP's comments,

**connect.js:-**
Changes- No need of the connectDB param, using `module.exports` functionality.

```
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var connectDB = {};

  connectDB.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //db params
  });

  connectDB.connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connectDB.connection.threadId);
  });

module.exports = connectDB;
```

**dbManager.js:-**

```
var db = require('./connect');//removed the parameter
//use db variable to process queries as returned from the above require statement.
var test_connection = db.connection.query('SELECT * FROM `test`', function (error, results, fields) {
  console.log(results);
});

exports.test = test_connection;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help & explanation. I tried to follow your guide, but still got an error. I updated the information about this on my question

Comment: I don't see the update. Can you try updating it again.

Comment: Its updated on my browser. Could u try to refresh the page? Thanks

Comment: The problem might be here -> `console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);` change **connection** to **connectDB.connection**

Editing my answer.

Comment: I changed it but the error still persists. I think its because `connectDB` is not passed successfully

Comment: Have edited my answer. However I'm not a mysql package expert :) You can try if the above code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
         **you can do it like this
            connection.js**


         var mysql=require('mysql');
         // Database Connection
         var connection = mysql.createConnection({
              host     : hostname,
              user     :username,
              password : password,
              database : databasename,
              multipleStatements:true
         });
         try {
                connection.connect();

             } catch(e) {
                  console.log('Database Connetion failed:' + e);
                    }

       module.exports=connection;


       **you can use this connection file in your dbmanager file like 
         this..**

         var db = require('./connection.js');var test_connection = 
               connection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(err,result) { 
                         console.log(result);
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you? You can have a file that returns a connection object from the pool:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = function() {
    var dbConfig = {...};
    var database = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);

    return {
        getConnection: function(callback) {
            // callback(error, connection)
            database.getConnection(callback);
        }
    };
};
```

Wherever you need to use it, you can require it as follows:

```
var connector = require('./db-connector')();
```

Then use it like this:

```
connector.getConnection(function(error, connection) {
    // Some code...

    // Be sure to release the connection once you're done
    connection.release();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I store config data to pass around on my node server. I call it config.js and .gitignore it. I keep a sample copy called config.sample.js

```
let config = {};
config.mysql-host='localhost' || process.env.MYSQL_HOST;
config.mysql-user='me' || process.env.MYSQL_USER;
config.mysql-secret='secret' || process.env.MYSQL_SECRET;
config.mysql-database='my_db' || process.env.MYSQL_DB;
module.exports = config; //important you don't have access to config without this line.
```

To use it I would do the following.

```
const config = require('./config');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: config.host,
user: config.user,
password: config.password,

});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if(err) {
  console.error(`error connecting: ${err.stack});
  return;
  }
  console.log(`connected`);
});

const test_connection = connectDB.connection.query('SELECT * FROM `test`'(error, results, fields) => {
  console.log(results);
});
```