# Pass a variable into a NodeJS require setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, node-modules

In my nodeJS app, Im trying to build a helper library that connects to my external service.

I want to get to

```
    const client = require('./myService')(serviceKey);
```

in the app I want to be able to call multiple functions, eg:

```
    var healthcheckState = client.healthcheck();
    var functionOneBool = client.someFunction('variable0','variable1');
```

I found several SO posts about how to do this;
[How to pass variables into NodeJS modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380561/how-to-pass-variables-into-nodejs-modules)
[How can I pass a variable while using `require` in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146980/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-while-using-require-in-node-js)

But I couldn't figure out how to adapt them.

This is myService.js

```
    module.exports = function(serviceKey) {
        var modules = {};
        modules.healthcheck = {
            function(){
                console.log('I have a heartbeat!');
            }
        };
        return modules;
      };
```

When I try to run:

```
    const client = require('./myService')('abc123');
    client.healthcheck();
```

Im told that **client.healthcheck is not a function**

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Let's think out loud. 1. the require method is returning a value, in your case its returning modules, which you have set as an object in your myService.js, You're also setting a property of 'healthcheck' which you're defining as an object. So far we see you're returning: 'modules' as an object with a module.healthcheck as an object. So you're modules.healthcheck as an object is not callable and is therefore not a function. An minimum, so far you should redefine module.healthcheck as a function expression instead of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Syntax error in your code.
You are making a `modules` object, and in module Object you are making an object without any key, and `function` as value.

Basically you are making: `obj = { healthcheck: { func } };` You need it ot be `obj = { healthcheck: func }`

```
module.exports = function(serviceKey) {
    const modules = {};
    modules.healthcheck = function(){
            console.log('I have a heartbeat!');
        }
    return modules;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a unit test for this scenario would not be an ideal test. What about placing a setter function on your service?

```
let client = require('./myService');
client.setServiceKey('abc123');
// or
client.setServiceKey(process.env.SERVICE_KEY);

let myReturnValue = client.myDifferenctCalls();
```

Then you can set up a nice, tokenValid or tokenNotValid unit test to go with it.

Next think it through 1. your require method returns a value, in your case its returning modules as an object in your myService.js, You're also setting a property of 'healthcheck' which you're defining as an **object**. So far we see you're returning: 'modules' as an object with a prop module.healthcheck as an object. So your modules.healthcheck as an object is not [[callable]] and is therefore not a function. At minimum, so far you should redefine module.healthcheck as a function expression instead of an object. So I've given the answer in writing, but you need to code it.